# How to create multilevel navigation with AMP using walker-menu?

Tags: wordpress, amp-html, wp-nav-walker

I am using wordpress with AMP.
I found this code, but it only shows me 2 levels: https://github.com/better-studio/better-amp/blob/master/includes/classes/class-better-amp-menu-walker.php

This is how I call the menu

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'              => 'primary',
            'depth'             => 2,
            'container'         => 'nav',
            'container_class'   => 'amp-menu swipe-menu hidden-desktop',
            'container_id'      => 'amp-menu',
            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
            'walker'            => new Walker_AMP_Menu())
        );
```

Is there any way to make it multilevel?
Sample:

```
item 1
item 2
  -item 2.1
  -item 2.1
     -item 2.1.1
     -item 2.1.2
item 3
item 4
item 5
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `depth` to `3`?

Comment: Yes, but I think the menu code: [link]https://github.com/better-studio/better-amp/blob/master/includes/classes/class-better-amp-menu-walker.php only works for 2 levels

Comment: The Amp menu walker does not appear to have a depth restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem is in this section, it only allows 2 levels

```
if ( $this->has_children && $depth == 0) {
        add_theme_support( 'better-amp-has-nav-child', TRUE );

        $this->start_accordion( $output, $depth );

        $output .= '<h6 class=' .$depth.'><span ' . $class_names . '>';
        $output .= $this->get_anchor_tag( $item, $depth, $args, $id );
        $output .= '</span></h6>';

        $this->start_accordion_child_wrapper( $output, $depth );

    } else {

        $output .= '<span id='.$depth.' ' . $class_names . '>';
        $output .= $this->get_anchor_tag( $item, $depth, $args, $id );
        $output .= '</span>';

    }
```